# Postgresql: comportamiento lunático al calcular AVG

Tags: postgresql, sql

Me está ocurriendo algo totalmente sorprendente al tratar de calcular la media de una columna con Postgresql 12.

Tengo esta tabla:

[image: Tabla puentes]

Cuando intento calcular la media con la sentencia sql correspondiente me arroja un resultado absolutamente incorrecto y no consigo explicarme qué estoy haciendo mal.

SELECT AVG(peso_maximo)
FROM puente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que evidentemente es incorrecto pues la media es 20283,75.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No consigo reproducir tu problema: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJeYcsjfy5fkDBT6yMwtpS/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJeYcsjfy5fkDBT6yMwtpS/0). Incluso en la versión más antigua soportada por db-fidle, la 9.4, funciona correctamente el cálculo de la media.

Answer (score 1):

He estado ciego. Postgresql al operar devuelve un dato de tipo numeric sin constreñirse a la precisión y escala del operando.

Basta con agrandar un poco la celda para poder ver el resultado. Espero que la pregunta - respuesta pueda ayudar a alguien al que le pase lo mismo que a mi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ummm, ¿qué estás usando para hacer las consultas SQL? Esto parece un error (bug) de la aplicación gráfica que has usado, y no de postgresql ni de la consulta en sí.

Answer (score 1):

Tras ver que el fallo que sufres es un fallo de visualización y no de cálculo, te puedo recomendar que hagas una conversión al mismo tipo de datos usando [`CAST()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT CAST ( AVG(peso_maximo) AS NUMERIC(10,3) ) FROM puente;
```

De ese modo el resultado será `20283.750` en vez de `20283.750000000000`:

```
avg
20283.750
```

Ver ejemplo en línea:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJeYcsjfy5fkDBT6yMwtpS/1